# Symfony2 error after trying to persist entity: Unable to find Entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two entities, Series and Magazines, with a ManyToMany relationship.
When I try to add a new Serie, I use two routes (new and create), with the following code in the SerieController:

```
public function newAction($id = null)
    {
        $entity = new Serie();
        if ($id) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $mag = $em->getRepository('MangaBundle:Magazine')->find($id);
            $entity->addMagazine($mag);
            }
        $form   = $this->createForm(new SerieType(), $entity);

        return array(
            'serie' => $entity,
            'form'   => $form->createView(),
        );
    }
```

And:

```
public function createAction(Request $request)
    {
        $entity  = new Serie();
        $form = $this->createForm(new SerieType(), $entity);
        $form->bind($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($entity);
            $magazines = $entity->getMagazines();
            foreach($magazines as $magazine){
                $em->persist($magazine);
            }
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('serie_show', array('id' => $entity->getId())));
        }

        return array(
            'serie' => $entity,
            'form'   => $form->createView(),
        );
```

But then, when I try to do it, I get this:

> ```
> Unable to find Serie entity.
>
> 404 Not Found - NotFoundHttpException
> ```

With the following error:

> INFO - Matched route "serie_show" (parameters: "_controller":
>   "MyList\DB\MangaBundle\Controller\SerieController::showAction", "id":
>   "create", "_route": "serie_show")

Which shouldn't be happening, having this in the showAction:

```
public function showAction($id)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $entity = $em->getRepository('MangaBundle:Serie')->find($id);

        if (!$entity) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Serie entity.');
        }


        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);

        return array(
            'serie'      => $entity,
            'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        );
    }
```

I cna't figure out what is happening to send 'create' as id in the redirect in the createAction. Can anyone help me figure out what I'm missing?

Comment: Is `Serie` persisted in the DB ? How the URL for the show look like ? I mean do you see the number at the end of it ?

Comment: Nope, it's not persisted, and the url doesn't have the number it should have.

Comment: Open `config_dev.yml` and change seet `intercept_redirects: true` There is an error `createAction`. Personally I don't understand the `foreach` part.

Answer (score 0):

Take a closer look at that INFO notice (by the way it's not an error, it's a log entry):

> "id": "create"

Here's what's happening:

1. "create" is being passed as argument for `showAction`.
2. Entity Manager searches for a `Serie` entity identified with `create` id.
3. It doesn't find it and throws `NotFoundException`.

Are you sure that `Serie` entity is set up correctly? Usually `id` should be auto-generated integer:

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $id;
```

It seems that when new `Serie` is instantiated, it gets "created" string as `$id` value.

Also, I can't figure out what's the purpose of `newAction` here. It returns a big array, and nothing more than that.

I think that something is messed up with routing and that `createAction()` is called from somewhere else than you think, because for sure it's not called from `newAction()` in `SerieController`.